# aggregation of categorical variables

Tags: aggregation

I want to aggregate my database including the categorical variables, so that each row represents multiple rows from the original data (e.g., based on student ID). Each column needs to hold the most common value within the original data (per aggregated ID).
Example: I want to aggregate my data by student and see the most frequent level of my categorical variables - for example:

```
student   class 
a          h        (being h the dominant level for the variable "class"
```

I am working with R studio

[image]

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for assuming your data is stored in the data frame mydf:  table(mydf\$student, mydf$class).  But it's still not entirely clear from your question whether you are trying to obtain tabulations or the most prevalent class for each unique student.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am actually aiming to obtain a df with the most prevalent class for each unique student!

Comment: I am actually aiming to obtain a df with the most prevalent class for each unique student! any help?

Comment: I suggest adding 'r' to the tags to increase traction ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in fact you wish to create a new data frame that aggregates (or summarizes in `dplyr`) multiple students into a single row per student in which your specified categorical columns will hold the most common value, you can use the `Mode` function from the `DescTools` library, and `summarise` with `dplyr`. You should note that you may well run into trouble, like in your example data, when you have no, or multiple values that are the most common (multi-modal). You will need to decide what to do.

This can get you started:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
install.packages("DescTools")
library(DescTools)

#create sample data tibble (similar to data frame)
data <- data.frame(student=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
               subject=c('aze','sdf','hjk','uio','okn','uhv'),
               class=c('h','h','f','l','h','l'),
               num=c(2,2,3,5,2,6))


# returns a single mode. Will return NA if multimodal by default.
# To return the first mode if multimodal, add "FALSE" to the second condition
get_mode = function(x, multimodal.na="TRUE"){
  modes <- Mode(x)
  if (multimodal.na=="FALSE" | length(modes)==1) {
    return(modes[1]) 
  } else {
    return(modes[length(modes)+1])
  }
}

# tests
data_mode <- data %>% group_by(student) %>% summarise(md_subject = get_mode(subject, multimodal.na = "FALSE"),
                                                      md_class = get_mode(class, multimodal.na = "FALSE"),
                                                      md_num = get_mode(num, multimodal.na = "FALSE"))
data_mode2 <- data %>% group_by(student) %>% summarise(md_subject = get_mode(subject),
                                                      md_class = get_mode(class),
                                                      md_num = get_mode(num))
```

Now lets view the two datums above:

```
> data_mode
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  student md_subject md_class md_num
  <fct>   <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
1 a       aze        h             2
2 b       uio        l             5
3 c       okn        h             2
> data_mode2
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  student md_subject md_class md_num
  <fct>   <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
1 a       NA         h             2
2 b       uio        l             5
3 c       NA         NA           NA
```

Comment: THANK YOU YUVAL!

Comment: YOU SAVED MY PROJECT!

Comment: @F.Ha glad I could help!
If you can accept and/or vote up this answer that would be appreciated :)

Comment: I did voted of course, but i got this:... Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @F.Ha of course. I meant accepting the answer by clicking on the little V next to it, sorry :)